# Curl - disable all the jenkins jobs, that match a pattern

Tags: shell, curl, jenkins

In my shell script I disable a Jenkins job by using curl

```
curl --fail --silent -u user:password -X POST "http://server/job/testjob_1/disable"
```

But now I need to disable all the jenkins jobs, that match a pattern.

So in my case, after disabling **testjob_1**, I must also find and disable jenkins jobs like **testjob_1_TEST**, **testjob_1_TEST4**, **testjob_1_TEST5** and so on (according to the patter testjob_1*).

How can I do it? How can I get a list of jobs, according to a pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it

```
curl --fail --silent -u user:password "http://server/job/api/json" | jq --raw-output '.jobs | .[] | .name' |grep testjob_1
```

I get a list of jobs by using this command.